# VB.net Error sending a binary object to a web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap, xml-serialization

I need to pass a block of binary data to a web service.  The object I'm passing is part of an API, so the Serialize/Deserialize/Byte functions are built-in to the API class.  It is not explicitly XML Serializable as far as I can tell.

Unfortunately, whenever I pass the data to my web service, even as an encoded string, the service returns a "(400) Bad Request" error.  If I remove the encoded data and replace the variable with a simple string, an appropriate response is returned, ruling out authentication, service errors, etc.

```
'Convert the byte array into an encoded string'
Dim unicodeEncoder As New UnicodeEncoding()
Dim serializedData As String = unicodeEncoder.GetString(myObject.Bytes).Trim()
Dim webAuth As New myWebService.ServiceSoapClient
MessageBox.Show(webAuth.VerifyFeatureSet(serializedData , "", "", "", ""))
```

Any suggestions for how I can accomplish this?  If I need to encode the data a different way, please include a snippet for decoding it on the far end.

Comment: Have you tried using 64Base conversion?

Comment: I'm able to send the data in Base64, but when I go to get it back out, I receive the following message:  Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.  Using this code: Dim bt As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Trim(base64DataString))

Comment: Came home from work and now it runs.  Maybe I forgot to build after making some other changes.  Thanks for the help.  Base64 encoding works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to Base64 worked perfectly.  (Thanks, Blue)

Send to web service:

```
webAuth.VerifyFeatureSet(System.Convert.ToBase64String(myObject.Bytes)
```

Web service receive and decode:

```
Dim byteObject As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(serializedData)
```